# java while loop error? additional outputs what is the wrong with the code?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
class demoWhile{        
public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException{
        char ch = (char)System.in.read();
        while(ch!='w'){
            System.out.println("Hi"+ch);
            ch = (char)System.in.read();
        }
    }
}
```

-first I gave the input a 'r' and expected output was "Hir" then input option but instead received output was Hir, Hi, Hi then the input option. why it shows two additional Hi, Hi?

Comment: Are you running this on windows and pressed Enter after the 'r'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you run this on a windows machine and pressed Enter after the 'r'. If that's not the case, ignore this answer.

The enter is understood as a linebreak, which consist of the two bytes `0D 0A` on windows. In String literals these are usually expressed as `"\r\n"`.

That causes three characters to be read: 'r', '\r' (char 13) and '\n' (char 10).

Your code processes them individually, so the output is

```
Hir
Hi\r
Hi\n
```

But the \r and \n dont get displayed since they only have an effect (on windows) when you combine them.

Comment: is there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: As far as I know, you need the Enter only to signal the shell (command prompt) that you are working with that your input is complete. The linebreak then signals the shell to forward all input to the application. You could "filter" this input by not printing/doing anything when ``ch==13||ch==10``.

Comment: I got a way to clear the buffer.. This will work I Got this from a book..